# Scrolling through ListView with some images very laggy

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

I've got the below screen that contains some images (6 per visible page). Scrolling up and down seems quite laggy to me. It's like it's rendering the images again. Scrolling back up seems worse than scrolling down.

Anyone know how to increase performance in such an area to create a nice smooth scroll?

**Update**: The images and text is all retrieved from my SQLite database. The list is created using SimpleCursorAdapter.

[image: Gallery]

```
private class HistoryViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder 
{
    //private int wallpaperNumberIndex;
    private int timeIndex;
    private int categoryIndex;
    private int imageIndex;

    private java.text.DateFormat dateFormat;
    private java.text.DateFormat timeFormat;
    private Date d = new Date();

    public HistoryViewBinder(Context context, Cursor cursor) 
    {
        dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
        timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);

        //wallpaperNumberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HistoryDatabase.KEY_WALLPAPER_NUMBER);
        timeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HistoryDatabase.KEY_TIME);
        categoryIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HistoryDatabase.KEY_CATEGORY);
        imageIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HistoryDatabase.KEY_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "setViewValue");

        if (view instanceof TextView)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "TextView");
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;

            if (columnIndex == timeIndex)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "timeIndex");
                d.setTime(cursor.getLong(columnIndex));
                tv.setText(timeFormat.format(d) + "  " + dateFormat.format(d));
                return true;
            }
            else if (columnIndex == categoryIndex)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "categoryIndex");
                tv.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (view instanceof ImageView)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "ImageView");
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;

            if (columnIndex == imageIndex)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "imageIndex");
                byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
                Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would help a lot if you could post the code of your getView method that creates the single list items.

Comment: @Janusz I don't use getView. I use SimpleCursorAdapter to create this view.

Comment: Can you then post the creation of the SimpleCursorAdapter and if you are extending the cursor adapter the bindView method?

Comment: @Janusz I've posted the SimpleCursorAdapter class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that each image is decoded at the moment the view is prepared for showing. The ListView will recycle your views that means that at the moment a view leaves the screen it will be reused and therefore the image will be overwritten and garbage collected. If the item reenters the screen the image has to be decoded from the database again.

The decoding is reasonable fast but if the user changes the position in the list very quickly all the decoding calls will make your list very laggy.

I would implment something like an ImageCache. A class that holds a Map with [WeakReferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to images. Everytime you want to display an image you take a look if the image is allready in the map and if the WeakReference still points to an object, if this is not the case you need to decode the image and then store it in the map.

Take a look at the lazy loading questions, these will show you how to put the decoding in a background task and then update the list the moment the images are loaded. It is a bit more effort but it can make the list much much more faster. If you are going to use the code example from the lazy loading questions try to use [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of Threads to do the decoding in.

Comment: You're correct. Everytime I would scroll back up into view it would retrieve the image from the DB, decode it and display it. Do you have any examples where they use AsyncTasks for the decoding instead of Threads?

Answer (score 2):

Here is sth, what you should read, and it should help you to solve problem (whole Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently part):
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

If your images are not the proper size, they are being scaled on the fly, which is not a cheap operation, particularly for large images. Be sure that you are loading thumbnails, not the wallpaper, out of your database.

Also, you can use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to find out where your time is being spent.

Comment: I am using thumbnails but not the exact size you see there... so they do get resized down. Do you think it would be better to store a second even smaller thumbnail that will only be used for the list? I use the original thumbnail to display an AlertDialog with it inside it once you click on the list item (so I need the larger thumbnail).

Comment: @mlevit: It is worth a try, or use Traceview to see if your time seems to be spent in resizing code. It is also conceivable that loading blobs out of SQLite is unusually slow -- I've never stored images in a table and so have no idea of the performance characteristics.